# trying to find if a character appears successively in a string

Tags: python

Simple script to find if the second arguement appears 3 times successively in the first arguement. I am able to find if the second arguement is in first and how many time etc but how do i see if its present 3 times successively or not ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import string

def three_consec(s1,s2) :


    for i in s1 : 
        total = s1.count(s2)
        if total > 2:
            return "True"   

print three_consec("ABABA","A")
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`total = s1.count(s2)` will give you the number of `s2` occurrences in `s1` regardless of your position `i`.

Instead, just iterate through the string, and keep counting as you see characters `s2`:

```
def three_consec (string, character):
    found = 0
    for c in string:
        if c == character:
            found += 1
        else:
            found = 0

        if found > 2:
            return True

    return False
```

Alternatively, you could also do it the other way around, and just look if “three times the character” appears in the string:

```
def three_consec (string, character):
    return (character * 3) in string
```

This uses the feature that you can multiplicate a string by a number to repeat that string (e.g. `'A' * 3` will give you `'AAA'`) and that the `in` operator can be used to check whether a substring exists in a string.